# PHP => $_SESSION Array only keeps last variable

Tags: php, arrays, session

I'm building an interface for an online shop, where every item is a FORM and the BUY button is a submit,it submits the name and price of the clicked form and that data is displayed on a CONFIRM ORDER page. On that confirm order page I've created an array as follows

```
if (!isset($input_order_arr)) {
  $input_order_arr = array();
}
```

After that I fetch the posted variables and push them into the array

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
  if (!empty($_POST['item-title'])  && !empty($_POST['item-price'])) {
    $item_title = test_input($_POST['item-title']);
    $item_price = test_input($_POST['item-price']);
    array_push($input_order_arr,$item_title,$item_price);
  }
}

$_SESSION['chosen_item'] = $input_order_arr;
```

***NOTE** : test_input is a function that does striplashes , htmlspecialchars and htmltrim, for security purposes. (someone might edit the value of the item via the Chrome developer console? not sure if that holds any threat though)

And after that the value is displayed in a table like so

```
              <?php if (isset($_SESSION['chosen_item'])) {
                foreach ($_SESSION['chosen_item'] as $value) {
                  echo "<td>" . $value . "</td>";
                }
              }  ?>
```

And here comes the problem.

If you order an item its price and name are displayed, but if u go back and you order another item, the previous item and its price are lost, as if its not adding new lines to the array,but replacing the old ones, or the session only saves data from one action, which wouldn't make any sense, since thats what $_SESSION is about, the code is presented with `session_start();` in every page that is using the $_SESSION variable.

**Main Question - Why could it be that the $_SESSION Array is losing its older inputs?**

Comment: I don't see how `$input_order_arr` and `$_SESSION['chosen_item']` are connected.

Comment: Where are you setting the $_SESSION['chosen_item'] element?

Comment: question updated

Comment: By `$input_order_arr = array();` You are updating the variable with empty array

Comment: @FrayneKonok
ONLY if its empty
if (!isset($input_order_arr)) {
  $input_order_arr = array();
}

Comment: `$_SESSION['chosen_item'] = $input_order_arr;` should be done inside `if`

Comment: @u_mulder Nope, didnt work, tried it just now.... :/

Comment: Check that array `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')`

Comment: Are we supposed to assume that you have actually done a `session_start()` in this code somewhere? Hopefully right after the first `<?php` in this code

Comment: Stop using `test_input`, it's nonsense. It doesn't even live up to its own name!

Comment: @RiggsFolly i have stated this in the final 3 lines of the problem

Comment: **Note:** this code `$_SESSION['chosen_item'] = $input_order_arr;` will overwrite `$_SESSION['chosen_item']` so if you thought you were adding to the `$_SESSION['chosen_item']` array you are not

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I don't think the problem with the `session_start()`

Comment: you need $_SESSION['chosen_item'][]=$input_order_arr;  your overwriting the same index instead of creating new one

Comment: In a nutshell, you're never *reading from* `$_SESSION['chosen_item']`, you're only ever completely overwriting it. How do you expect items will get *added to it* that way?

Comment: You need to push the generated arry into `$_SESSION['chosen_item']` again and again, so that you got new orders into the session for everytime.

Comment: `array_push($_SESSION['chosen_item'], $item_title, $item_price);` in the loop and loose this line `$_SESSION['chosen_item'] = $input_order_arr;` that is destroying you session data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could push directly into the session like this

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if (!empty($_POST['item-title'])  && !empty($_POST['item-price'])) {

        array_push($_SESSION['chosen_item'],
                    test_input($_POST['item-title']),
                    test_input($_POST['item-price'])
                  );
    }
}

//$_SESSION['chosen_item'] = $input_order_arr;
```

Or as your `test_input()` is likely doing nothing useful

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if (!empty($_POST['item-title'])  && !empty($_POST['item-price'])) {

        array_push($_SESSION['chosen_item'],
                    $_POST['item-title'],
                    $_POST['item-price']
                  );
    }
}
```

You might find this data easier to use later by doing

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if (!empty($_POST['item-title'])  && !empty($_POST['item-price'])) {

        array_push($_SESSION['chosen_item'],
                    array('title' => $_POST['item-title'],
                          'price' => $_POST['item-price']
                        )
                  );
    }
}
```

Comment: Approved answer bro ! Before this I was attempting to make it an array with keys and values , so I had to use a separate variable and than make the session take the array... Thanks brother ! Have a good one

Comment: I was wondering how you were going to make sense of the data later, added a suggestion to create a usable array of arrays

Comment: The item is displayed in a table which is in a form, clicking "finish order" does a submit and sends to the DB the item + price + user_name + userinputted phone and address for delivery + userinputted phone. I havent gotten to making that work yet, but it seems easier than this in any case :D

Answer (score 1):

you need `$_SESSION['chosen_item'][]=$input_order_arr;` your **overwriting** the same index  instead of creating **new one**

```
$_SESSION['chosen_item'][]=$input_order_arr;
```

Note : And also it should be moved inside the if statement .to avoid empty array storing in session

Comment: Yes, but he will be adding empty array elements every time there is no POST request.

Comment: yea yea.... I get what I did wrong.. blyat...thanks for your time and thorough explanation @JYoThI , Live long and prosper brother

Comment: glad to help you @DenislavKaragiozov

Answer (score -1):

When you go back, you basically are setting the chosen_item array element to empty, since $input_order_arr would not contain anything when you haven't submitted a form.

You should append to the session array only if there is a nonempty $input_order_arr array:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
  if (!empty($_POST['item-title'])  && !empty($_POST['item-price'])) {
    $item_title = test_input($_POST['item-title']);
    $item_price = test_input($_POST['item-price']);
    array_push($input_order_arr,$item_title,$item_price);

    $_SESSION['chosen_item'][] = $input_order_arr;
  }
}
```

Comment: NO need to use inside, Cause `array_push()` used